# List of useful Apache modules for PHP development

Tags: php, apache, module, apache2, wamp

I'm rethinking which modules I need for local PHP development. Which of these modules have you found essential for you, or rarely used, or never used for PHP development. Please share your experience, or share any other that aren't on this list.

- **a:** actions_module, alias_module, asis_module, auth_basic_module, auth_digest_module, authn_alias_module, authn_anon_module, authn_dbd_module, authn_dbm_module, authn_default_module, authn_file_module, authnz_ldap_module, authz_dbm_module, authz_default_module, authz_groupfile_module, authz_host_module, authz_owner_module, authz_user_module, autoindex_module
- **c:** cache_module, cern_meta_module, cgi_module, charset_lite_module
- **d:** dav_module, dav_fs_module, dav_lock_module, dbd_module, deflate_module, dir_module, disk_cache_module, dumpio_module
- **e:** env_module, expires_module, ext_filter_module
- **f:** file_cache_module, filter_module
- **h:** headers_module
- **i:** ident_module, imagemap_module, include_module, info_module, isapi_module
- **l:** ldap_module, logio_module, log_config_module, log_forensic_module
- **m:** mem_cache_module, mime_module, mime_magic_module
- **n:** negotiation_module
- **p:** proxy_module, proxy_ajp_module, proxy_balancer_module, proxy_connect_module, proxy_ftp_module, proxy_http_module
- **r:** rewrite_module
- **s:** setenvif_module, speling_module, ssl_module, status_module
  substitute_module
- **u:** unique_id_module, userdir_module, usertrack_module
- **v:** version_module, vhost_alias_module

Answer (score 3):

All these years, this list has been sufficient for me.

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the modules you don't use, both for security and performance.